# Why object field is not initialized when extending App?

Tags: scala

I have a simple object defined which extends App. The object initializes a field and has a method that tries to print it.

```
object ex extends App {

  val field: Int = 5

  def printField() = {
    println("field: ", field)
  }
}
```

Then I have another app that calls the "ex" object's method:

```
object MainAlgoRunner extends App {

  ex.printField()
}
```

The result that is printed is "(field: ,0)" - meaning that the "ex" field was not yet initialized... The same behavior I get if the field is declared as "final".

However, if the "ex" object is no longer extending App, the result that is printed is "(field: ,5)" - which means that, this time, the field was initialized.

I do not have any reasons for having "ex" object extending App. This was an overlook from the refactoring process.

Still, I am curious to understand why when "ex" is extending App, running the printField() method from MainAlgoRunner does not print the field value initialized. I assume it has something to do with how App is lazily initializing variables... but i lack the details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala's `App` trait extends `DelayedInit` and it is using `delayedInit()` method to execute code inside object's body. Your code is not running main method of `ex` object so it is not getting properly initialized. Try

```
object MainAlgoRunner extends App {
  ex.main(args) // this is important
  ex.printField()
}
```

to see the magic happen :)

Answer (score 2):

`DelayedInit` is [dropped](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/delayed-init.html) in Scala 3:

> The special handling of the `DelayedInit` trait is no longer
>   supported... the code is now run in the initializer of the object

This means your code would work as intended in Scala 3 without having to call `ex.main`.

Also note that `App` itself will eventually be [deprecated](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html)

> The previous functionality of `App`, which relied on the "magic"
>   `DelayedInit` trait, is no longer available. `App` still exists in
>   limited form for now, but it does not support command line arguments
>   and will be deprecated in the future.

in favour of `@main` annotation or an explicitly defined `main` method.